# WPF user control dependency property not binding

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, dependency-properties

I know there are many similar questions, I have read loads of them in the past day or so, but none of the solutions seem to help me.

I have a WPF user control, that is basically a souped-up `ComboBox`, on which I would like to enable data binding. I followed the code shown in the accepted answer to [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25341547/706346), but the binding isn't working.

A cut-down version of the content of the user control is as follows...

```
<UserControl x:Class="Sample.MyComboBox"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
    <ComboBox Name="EntityTb"
              IsEditable="True" />
</UserControl>
```

There's obviously  a lot more to it, but the rest isn't relevant to my question.

In the code-behind, I added a dependency property called `Text` as follows...

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty TextProperty
         = DependencyProperty.Register("Text", typeof(string),
  typeof(MyComboBox), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata() {
    BindsTwoWayByDefault = true,
    PropertyChangedCallback = TextChanged,
    DefaultUpdateSourceTrigger = UpdateSourceTrigger.PropertyChanged
  });


private static void TextChanged(DependencyObject d,
                             DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e) {
  MyComboBox cmb = (MyComboBox)d;
  cmb.EntityTb.Text = e.NewValue.ToString();
}

public string Text {
  get => (string)GetValue(TextProperty);
  set => SetValue(TextProperty, value);
}
```

I then tried using this on a WPF window. The view model has a `Customer` property, which has a `Name` property which I want to bind to the custom control...

```
<controls:MyComboBox Grid.Column="1"
     Text="{Binding Customer.Name, Mode=TwoWay}" />
```

The `Customer` property is nothing more complex than...

```
private Customer _customer;

public Customer Customer {
  get => _customer;
  set {
    if (_customer != value) {
      _customer = value;
      RaisePropertyChanged();
    }
  }
}
```

...and the `Customer` type itself is just a plain C# class...

```
public partial class Customer {
  public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

However nothing happens. When the window loads, the customer name is not shown in the combobox, and if I type anything in there, the model is not updated.

I've done a lot of searching, and all code samples seem to look like the one above. Anyone able to tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Can you share the `Customer` class and most importantly the `Name` property inside it?

Comment: @Bijington Added some more. Thanks

Comment: Did you assign the view model instance to the Window's DataContext? And did you make sure that you did **not** set the UserControl's DataContext?

Comment: Also note that updating `cmb.EntityTb.Text` in a PropertyChangedCallback only works in one direction. Instead of the PropertyChangedCallback, better use a two-way binding like `<ComboBox IsEditable="True" Text="{Binding Text, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=UserControl}, Mode=TwoWay}"/>`

Comment: @Clemens That last suggestion got me somewhere. The value now comes out of the view model and is set in the combobox, but if I change the combobox, the value isn't sent back to the view model. Any ideas? We're half-way there! Thanks

Comment: @Clemens No, ignore that last comment, it's working fine. I had forgotten the binding when I used the user control. Please add your suggestion as an answer and I'll accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Updating `cmb.EntityTb.Text` in a PropertyChangedCallback only works in one direction.

Instead of that, use a two-way binding like

```
<ComboBox IsEditable="True"
    Text="{Binding Text, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=UserControl}}"/>
```

As the `ComboBox.Text` property also binds two-way by default, setting `Mode=TwoWay` is redundant.